# How do you create a new variable with all the rows and values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I have a loop that i am having trouble with it. Im trying to create a new variable but the problem is it will only output the last row and values. Is there a way to create a new variable with all the rows and values

Here is an example. I have two list that are two dimensional list that are match .

```
a=[[9, 15, 25],[4, 14, 18, 25],[11, 12, 24, 25],[4, 8, 9, 26]] 
b=[[2, 4, 7, 13, 14],[3, 5, 8, 13, 14],[6, 9, 10, 13, 14],[5, 6, 7, 13, 15],[3, 4, 9, 13, 15],[2, 8, 12, 13, 15],[4, 6, 8, 14, 15],[2, 5, 9, 14, 15]]
```

But the problem is i would like to create new variable with all the rows and values?

```
for idx,item_a in enumerate(a):
    result = []
    a = set(item_a)
    for item_b in b:      
        result.append(list(a.intersection(item_b)))  
        Df="{} : {}".format(idx,result)
```

Comment: Edit your post and reformat your code, please

Comment: You're resetting `result` to an empty list at the top of each loop.

Comment: How do i reformat my code

Comment: create `result = []` before all `for`-loops to keep all values in `result`

Comment: I think I saw similar question with `Df="{} : {}".format(idx,result)` before. What do you try to do with this line ? It will not  create variable with all results - you would have to use list - like `result` - or dictionary to keep all results.

Comment: i am using a list.

Answer (score 0):

to create a list of all rows use `extend` for `a` and `b`

```py
a=[[9, 15, 25],[4, 14, 18, 25],[11, 12, 24, 25],[4, 8, 9, 26]] 
b=[[2, 4, 7, 13, 14],[3, 5, 8, 13, 14],[6, 9, 10, 13, 14],[5, 6, 7, 13, 15],[3, 4, 9, 13, 15],[2, 8, 12, 13, 15],[4, 6, 8, 14, 15],[2, 5, 9, 14, 15]]
```

```py
c=a[:]
c.extend(b)
```

value of `c` -

```py
[[9, 15, 25], [4, 14, 18, 25], [11, 12, 24, 25], [4, 8, 9, 26], [2, 4, 7, 13, 14], [3, 5, 8, 13, 14], [6, 9, 10, 13, 14], [5, 6, 7, 13, 15], [3, 4, 9, 13, 15], [2, 8, 12, 13, 15], [4, 6, 8, 14, 15], [2, 5, 9, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: so i tried to create result=[ ] but it will it will only print out the last row . i would like to print out all rows